# How can I mine a specific block?

Tags: block, miner-configuration, cgminer

How can I set my miner to mine a specific block?
like:   Block: 496705

I have tried looking in ccminer options for that it looks like there is no option like that.

Comment: That's an odd thing to want to do.  Can you explain why you want to do that?  It might help people find the best way to help you out!

Answer (score 1):

Mining software generally do not work like that. They don't have any idea of what is in the Bitcoin blockchain nor know how to construct a block (i.e. selecting transactions). Rather these mining software must connect to a server that will give it the pieces for the next block that the server wants the mining hardware to solve. So in order to mine at a specific block height, you must connect to and configure a server which provides the block data for the block that you want.

The easiest way to do this would be to use Bitcoin Core and reset its blockchain at a certain block height. To do so, you would use the `invalidateblock` command so that the blockchain's tip is the block prior to the height that you want to mine at. Then just point your mining software at Bitcoin Core and it will work on mining that next block which you want.

Comment: Thanks, My problem is that I have a stuck transaction for over a month and I want to release it :\

Comment: Unless you have a significant amount of hashrate, you won't be able to mine a block. Furthermore, it does not help you to mine at a certain block height. Please read https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it for what you can do about "stuck" transactions.